# Unable to initialize new marionette router

Tags: backbone.js, router, marionette

I am trying to create a new app router within a 'Products' module as shown below using marionette

```
@MyApp.module "ProductsModule", (ProductsModule, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
 class ProductsModule.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
   appRoutes:
    "products" : "listGoods"

 API =
  listGoods: ->
    console.log('list goods')

 App.addInitializer ->
  console.log('init app router')
  new ProductsModule.Router
    controller: API
```

The higher level App code is as follows

```
@MyApp = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

 App = new Marionette.Application

 App.addRegions
  headerRegion: "#header-region"
  mainRegion: "#main-region"
  footerRegion: "#footer-region"

 App.on "initialize:after", (options) ->
  if Backbone.history
    Backbone.history.start
      root: '/admin/'

 App
```

However after trying to run, the appRouter for Products Module did not run i.e. console.log did not print out anything to the console.

Am I missing something here?

UPDATE:
Adding more code to show where the app was started

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Admin</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "admin" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="header-region"></div>
    <div id="main-region" class="container">

      <a href="#products">sss</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-region"></div>

  //STARTING APP HERE
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    $(function() {
      MyApp.start();
    });
  <% end %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nothing instatiates? did you start the app?

Comment: Yes the Backbone.history.start() did start successfully (did a console log). Just that the 'ProductsModule.Router' did not start up

Comment: no i mean did you start the application by `App.start()` ? btw app should be lower case

Comment: yes I did. Let me update the OP

Comment: @pfried I have updated the OP to show where I started the app. One thing to note is that this layout will only to triggered if I call /admin. Do I need to define a root: '/admin/' somewhere in the router so that the route will work with /admin/product for example?

Comment: Maybe you should define the url root then : `Backbone.history.start({ root: "/admin/"})`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27608/discussion-between-pfried-and-zhen)

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
console.log('init app router')
  new ProductsModule.Router
    controller: API
```

in

```
App.on("initialize:after", function(){/*place code here*/})
```

Move

```
if Backbone.history
    Backbone.history.start
      root: '/admin/'
```

in

```
App.on("start", function(){/*place code here*/})
```